Why is sphinx-autoapi not updating my documentation from child classes?
I am in the process of implementing sphinx-autoapi for an existing project.
For this I am building the docs, and I am ironing out the errors one by one.
For one class in the library I fixed an issue, but the fix is not propagating to the child classes.
Here is my conf.py for sphinx:
...
extensions = ['autoapi.extension']
autoapi_dirs = ['../../library/']
autoapi_python_class_content = "both"
autoapi_keep_files = False
autoapi_options = [
    'members',
    'undoc-members',
    'private-members',
    'special-members',
    'show-inheritance',
    'show-module-summary',
    'imported-members',
]
html_theme = 'furo'
html_static_path = ['_static']

In BaseClass I had a docstring containing this:
Usage
-----
* some point with code block following
    print("this is some example code that should be formated")
    exit(0)

I changed it to this:
Usage
^^^^^
* some point with ``code`` block following
    .. code-block:: 

        print("this is some example code that should be formated")
        exit(0)

Which fixed it for the BaseClass, however all the child classes still have the old comment in them.
I tried to build afresh with make clean, rm docs/source/autoapi, pyclean ., and reboot for good measure, but when building I still have the old version of the comment in the built html docs (SPHINXOPTS="-E" make html).
The weird thing, is that I also cannot find any occurrences of the old comment in the folder.
rg -. "[very specific string that is only in the old comment]" does not return anything, yet it will still appear in the built docs.
I found that sphinx-autoapi implements caching, but only when keep files is turned on https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx-autoapi/issues/191.
There is also no mention of caching in the documentation.
I tried to build a minimal example, however there the fix propagated just fine.
I guess my question is, is there some undocumented caching, or how does a string appear in the docs that is not even in the repository?
